# Chernoff bound on the maximum of multinomial distribution

Tags: streaming-algorithm, chernoff-bounds

I am reading some heavy hitter (HH) papers
when I run into the following reduction theorem.
The theorem attempts to reduce
an HH problem with a very small tail frequency $\epsilon$
to multiple HH instances with higher tail frequencies.

More precisely,
the reduction utilizes a random hash function $h$
that throws an item index $i \in [n]$ to one of the $z$ bins.
Each bin will then become an HH instance.

[image: Screenshot of some arxiv paper]

The problem is, how do we know whether or not
each of the $z$ bins contains roughly $1/z$ of the heavy hitters?
The paper then claims in (2) that, the probability that
one of the bin contains more than $C \log(1/\delta)$ heavy hitters
is less than $\delta/3$.

### My Question

How to prove (2) using Chernoff bound, as is suggested by the paper?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/165519/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53916/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @D.W. It's a meta discussion, not rule.  It is also very common that mathoverflow and math.sx throw questions to each other because askers misjudge the difficulty.  I explained in the other post why I cross-post (that there is no discussion here).  Also it is obvious that my question is CS-related (I even gave them proper tags) so it deserves to stay here, IMHO.

Comment: On Stack Exchange meta generally sets policies, so it's more than just a discussion.  These posts don't follow the guidelines there (cross-linking, tailoring, "materially different").  Math Overflow and Math.SE have their own site-specific policies, which don't apply here (but even they have expectations/requirements: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1725/37212, https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2637/37212, https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/423/37212, https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5012/37212, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16288/14578).

Comment: My bad not linking the old question to the new one (while I did link the new to old and even make it clear in the title).  Thank you for doing that.  But *tailoring* and *materially different* is something I found difficult to do.  The fact that I manage to find `streaming-algorithm` and `chernoff-bounds` tags on both sites speaks for me.  I of course can ask for a proof here and a counter-example there for the sake of not repeating, but that's not helping anyone.  If you have other ideas, pardon my ignorance and I am willing to follow.

Comment: I have deleted the tcs one.  Hope that everyone is happy.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but the proper course of action in most SE sites is that you post here, wait a week (depending on your judgment), then delete the old post before adding the new post (if suitable). No post should stand on two sites at the same time, unless with a policy exception. This is not nitpicking, but this is pretty central to how people mostly want SE to function.